# How to update all the r packages in RStudio in Anaconda

Tags: r, anaconda, package, conda

I'm using RStudio in a renv environment in Anaconda. I want to update the r packages in renv all at once. Merv's command [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197113/updating-r-packages-in-anaconda-but-getting-a-clang-12-error/69200327#69200327) updates only one package at a time (in the following code it only updates the *askpass* package)

```
conda install -n renv -c conda-forge r-askpass
```

However, since I have a long list of r packages to be updated, I wonder if there is any command that would update all r packages at once. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Available Conda CLI Options

The CLI only offers two options:

- listing specific packages

  ```bash
  conda update pkg1 pkg2 ...
  ```
- updating all packages

  ```bash
  conda update --all
  ```

So, not anything where you can specify all R packages.

### Using a RegEx

One trick to get something in between would be to use the regex capability of `conda list` to obtain a list of matching packages, then use some UNIX commands to send these as arguments to the `conda update` command.

Here's what doing that for all packages that start with either `r-` or `bioconductor-` (the two most common prefixes for R packages) would look like:

```bash
# environment you wish to update
ENV_NAME=renv

# update all `r-` and `bioconductor-` packages
conda list -n ${ENV_NAME} '^(r|bioconductor)-' | \
  grep -vE '^#' | cut -f1 -d' ' | \
  xargs conda update -n ${ENV_NAME} -d
```

**Important Note**: I include the `-d` (dry run) flag in `conda update` to prevent automatic acceptance of proposed changes, which seems to be triggered by the use of `xargs` here. I strongly recommend using this *as is* first (always review the changes!), and then after reviewing, execute again without the `-d`.

Comment: Hi, merv. Thank you so much for answering my question again. I ran your code in the terminal as instructed. What happened was that, after running your code, the message returned from the terminal says that all packages were updated. But when I entered RStudio in Anaconda and click the update button under the package pane, there was still a list of packages there, not all of them were updated. Anyways, using regex and Unix commands is too far away from what I know for now. Again, I appreciate your answer and hope you have a nice day!

Comment: @KaiLi so you ran it without the last `-d` at the end?

Comment: Hi merv. I first ran the command with -d and then ran it without -d as instructed. I re-tried your command "conda install -n renv -c conda-forge r-askpass" for each of the packages remaining in the update list. Some of them were able to be updated while others showed that the package was all up to date from CLI (but are still in the update list in RStudio GUI). It is valuable to learn that updating packages through different package managers can lead to serious problems especially when compilation is needed :)